# Google spreadsheets: how to a insert pivot table in the active sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I'm trying to add a pivot table in the same sheet in which I have charts and other analysis,but when I try to add a pivot table it creates a new sheet.

I am trying to convert an Excel dashboard into Google spreadsheet dashboard.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply select the cells of the pivot table you want to copy and then copy and paste it in the spreadsheet or sheet where you want it. If you want to, you can then delete the pivot table sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have created the pivot table you can move it using CTRL + X. Just select all the table then use CTRL + X and paste wherever you want it, the problem is that once you change the data in the pivot table and it gets bigger you may overwrite other information in other cells, so you have to be very careful with that.

This is the only way I have found in Google Docs since there is no "move" option.

Answer (score -1):

You can just reference it rather than deleting. This is a much better practice - this way you can update the pivot table without recreating it.

To reference from one sheet to another use the following formula in the top left cell of where you want to copy it :

```
={Sheet1!A1:K}
```

This will copy columns A through K.